# Change plugin author after someone leaves the company

Tags: plugins, wordpress.org

My company owns several plugins on Wordpress.org.  The original creator of these plugins created them using his own Wordpress account, and has now left the company.  How can we assume ownership of these plugins (preferably without contacting the former employee)?

Comment: _"preferably without contacting the former employee"_ ... that seems to be the tough part.

Answer (score 1):

Write an email to `plugins@wordpress.org` and explain the situation. But I don’t think this will be easy. You have to prove your ownership.

Answer (score 0):

if you have repository access just update the plugin and upload to the repository . a simple email to the old employee is the easiest and most direct on the basis of updating it .. otherwise your stuck with Toscho's answer